# Equation numbering error

Tags: math-mode

I want to number my equation, as depicted in the figure, like (1), (2), etc. . However, it elicits an error message. The code is below.

[image]

```
\begin{equation}    
\[
CHA_P=1-\sum_{\substack{x\in S\\O(x)=T \text{ or } O_n(x)=T-R(x);\ s_{n1}=s_{n2}=0}}^{n} \pi(x)
\]
\end{equation}
```

Comment: you can not start math in math `\begin{equation}    
\[`  delete the `\[` and `\]`  the equation enviornment is display math already.

Comment: Remove the pair `\[` `\]`. The equation environment is already in math mode. The LateX construct `\[ ... \]` is for *unnumbered* equations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use both equation and `\[` and `\]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
CHA_P=1-\sum_{\substack{x\in S\\O(x)=T \text{ or } O_n(x)=T-R(x);\ s_{n1}=s_{n2}=0}}^{n} \pi(x)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

To write correctly in the sum several rows that contains more informations is `\substack` as from the previous answer.

I have used another different approach, i.e. to use a little matrix called `\smallmatrix` that it has the similar effect of `\substack`. After I have fix the space using symmetrical space in math-mode called `\mkern-80mu`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
CHA_P=1- {\mkern-80mu}\sum_{\begin{smallmatrix}
x\in S\\ 
O(x)=T \text{ or } O_n(x)=T-R(x);\\ 
s_{n_1}=s_{n_2}=0\\ 
\end{smallmatrix}}^n  {\mkern-80mu} \pi(x)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not mean to answer the question, because Ulrike Fischer do it already. However, this is the way I would write the equation if I were you:

1. I think CHA is somewhat like a function, or something instead of *C* × *H* × *A*<sub>*P*</sub>. Therefore I use `\DeclareMathOperator`.
2. I think you want *s*<sub>*n*<sub>1</sub></sub> instead of *s*<sub>*n1*</sub>.
3. I make some rearrangements of the items below `\sum`.
4. I think some spaces in the equations below `\sum` should be added in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cha}{CHA}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\cha_P=1-\sum_{%
    \substack{%
        x\,\in\,S\\[2pt]
        s_{n_1}\,=\,s_{n_2}\,=\,0\\[2pt]
        O(x)\,=\,T \text{ or } O_n(x)\,=\,T\,-\,R(x)
    }
}^{n} \pi(x)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]